# Проверка поиска в базе данных

Tags: java, jdbc

Как реализовать проверку на наличие нужного поля в БД. Если да, то выводим поле на экран. Если нет, то выводит сообщение об отсутствии записи.

```
public void searchNumber() throws SQLException {

    String QUERY = "select * from telephonebook.phonenumbers where name = (?) ";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(QUERY);

    System.out.print("Enter name and surname ==> ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    preparedStatement.setString(1, name);

    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        System.out.println(resultSet.getInt("id") + " " + resultSet.getString("name") + " "
                + resultSet.getInt("number"));
    }
    preparedStatement.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если запрос вернул пустой ResultSet, то первый же вызов метода next вернет false. Поэтому можно сделать проверку, перед считыванием результатов:

```
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

if(!resultSet.next){
    System.out.println("Информация отсутствует");
}
```

Comment: Попробовал, все работает. Правда сразу не хотело выводить имеющийся информацию. Переделал конструкцию while на do while и все заработало. Спасибо.